# Find maximum from every column and put it in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

[image]
I manage to create a macro which take the information from a sheet, to transpose the information and now I want to find the maximum value.

In the picture it will be more easy to understand what I want:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this formula into cell in second sheet :

```
=MAX(Sheet1!A:A)
```

For example, `=MAX(Sheet1!B:B)`, `=MAX(Sheet1!C1:C10)` and ...